# Weird result with std::chrono::duration_cast for 1 second and 2 second

Tags: c++, c++11, output, duration, c++-chrono

I am running a simple program where, I take a `time_point` with `system_clock::now` then `this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1))` and again a `time_point` with `system_clock::now`.

Now if I add some extra `duration` to the 1st `time_point`, it gives exactly the same result for 1 and 2 seconds!

Here is the [demo code](http://ideone.com/3y4747):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

void CheckDuration (std::chrono::duration<int> seconds)
{
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + seconds;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  cout << "Difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop-start).count() << endl;
}

int main ()
{
  CheckDuration(std::chrono::duration<int>(0));  // Difference = 1
  CheckDuration(std::chrono::duration<int>(1));  // Difference = 0 
  CheckDuration(std::chrono::duration<int>(2));  // Difference = 0  <=== ???
  CheckDuration(std::chrono::duration<int>(3));  // Difference = -1
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is clarifying to add output with finer units, for example:

```
cout << "Difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop-start).count() << endl;
```

For me, for the 3rd case (argument 2 seconds), the output is:

```
Difference = -998
```

(that is in milliseconds)

To analyze this, let `T0` represent the time `now()` is first called in `CheckDuration`.  So:

```
start == T0 + 2s
```

`stop` is called at T0, plus 1 second for sleeping, plus a tiny bit of processing time we can call *epsilon*.  So:

```
stop == T0 + 1s + epsilon
```

Subtracting these two we get:

```
T0 + 1s + epsilon - (T0 + 2s)
```

simplifying:

```
epsilon - 1s
```

In my case, *epsilon* == 2ms

`duration_cast` has the behavior of *truncate towards zero* when the conversion can not be made exactly.  So -998ms truncates to 0s.  For other duration and time point rounding modes which may be helpful in your computations, see:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html